# \tkzDrawCircle[R] does not work in OS X, but work in online compiler

Tags: tkz-euclide

I have the following simple code which works on overleaf (creating circle)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (F) at (9.782962809280217,-6.349059818244973);
\coordinate (E) at (7.2796787851796365,-5.206667413876115);
\coordinate (G) at (7.572827128491371,-5.843163808832608);
\tkzDefCircle[circum](E,G,F) \tkzGetPoint{O} \tkzGetLength{rayon}
\tkzDrawCircle[R](O,\rayon pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The same code just doesn't work on my computer, using MacTex 2022. I have confirmed that my tkz-euclide package is version 4.25.

Here is the error: (it's something about `Package pgf Error: No shape named 1 is known`)

```
Rc files read:
  /Users/ajat/Library/TeXShop/bin/latexmkrcedit
  /Users/ajat/Library/TeXShop/bin/tslatexmk/pdflatexmkrc
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 17 Mar. 2022. Version 4.77, version: 4.77.
Latexmk: Getting log file 'trsas.log'
Latexmk: Examining 'trsas.fls'
Latexmk: Examining 'trsas.log'
Latexmk: applying rule 'pdflatex'...
Rule 'pdflatex': File changes, etc:
   Changed files, or newly in use since previous run(s):
  trsas.tex
Rule 'pdflatex': The following rules & subrules became out-of-date:
  pdflatex
------------
Run number 1 of rule 'pdflatex'
------------
------------
Running 'pdflatex  --synctex=1 --file-line-error  -recorder  "trsas.tex"'
------------
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./trsas.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-11-02>
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-euclide/tkz-euclide.sty
2022/09/23 4.25c tkz-euclide.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.te
x
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-li
sts.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def
) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/pgf.revision.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.c
ode.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-pdftex.d
ef
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-p
df.def)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.
code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/mathcolor.ltx))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.
tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigo
nometric.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.rando
m.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.compa
rison.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integ
erarithmetics.code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfint.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.co
de.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconst
ruct.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.co
de.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicst
ate.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransform
ations.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.cod
e.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.c
ode.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathproce
ssing.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.co
de.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.cod
e.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.cod
e.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.
code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.co
de.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretranspare
ncy.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorerdf.code.
tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.cod
e.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.
tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version
-0-65.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version
-1-18.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.cod
e.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothan
dlers.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.cod
e.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzlibraryangles.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzlibraryarrows.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryarrows.
code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryarrows.
meta.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzlibrarybackgrounds.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzlibrarycalc.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzlibrarydecorations.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduledecoration
s.code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzlibrarydecorations.markings.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/decorations/pgfli
brarydecorations.markings.code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzlibrarydecorations.pathreplacing.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/decorations/pgfli
brarydecorations.pathreplacing.code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzlibrarydecorations.shapes.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/decorations/pgfli
brarydecorations.shapes.code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzlibrarydecorations.text.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/decorations/pgfli
brarydecorations.text.code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzlibrarydecorations.pathmorphing.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/decorations/pgfli
brarydecorations.pathmorphing.code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzlibraryintersections.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryinterse
ctions.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryfpu.cod
e.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzlibrarymath.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzlibraryfpu.code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzlibraryplotmarks.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplotmar
ks.code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzlibrarypositioning.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzlibraryquotes.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzlibraryshapes.misc.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/shapes/pgflibrary
shapes.misc.code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzlibrarythrough.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xfp/xfp.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)))
 (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xpatch/xpatch.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty))
Local configuration file tkz-euclide.cfg found and used
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-euclide/tkz-euclide.cfg
2022/09/23 4.25c tkz-euclide.cfg
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-euclide/tkz-tools-eu-base.tex
2022/09/23 4.25c tkz-tools-eu-base.tex
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-euclide/tkz-tools-eu-utilitie
s.tex
2022/09/23 4.25c tkz-tools-eu-utilities.tex
) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-euclide/tkz-tools-eu-BB.tex
2022/09/23 4.25c tkz-obj-eu-BB.tex
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-euclide/tkz-obj-eu-grids.tex
2022/09/23 4.25c tkz-obj-eu-grids.tex
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-euclide/tkz-lib-eu-marks.tex
2022/09/23 4.25c tkz-lib-eu-marks.tex
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-euclide/tkz-tools-eu-text.tex
2022/09/23 4.25c tkz-tools-eu-text.tex
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-euclide/tkz-lib-eu-shape.tex
2022/09/23 4.25c tkz-lib-eu-shape.tex
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-euclide/tkz-obj-eu-axesmin.te
x
2022/09/23 4.25c tkz-obj-eu-axesmin
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-euclide/tkz-tools-eu-colors.t
ex
2022/09/23 4.25c tkz-tools-eu-colors
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-euclide/tkz-obj-eu-points.tex
2022/09/23 4.25c tkz-obj-eu-points.tex
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-euclide/tkz-obj-eu-draw-point
s.tex
2022/09/23 4.25c tkz-obj-eu-points.tex
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-euclide/tkz-tools-eu-angles.t
ex
2022/09/23 4.25c tkz-tools-eu-angles.tex
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-euclide/tkz-tools-eu-intersec
tions.tex
2022/09/23 4.25c tkz-tools-eu-intersections.tex
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-euclide/tkz-tools-eu-math.tex
2022/09/23 4.25c tkz-tools-eu-math.tex
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-euclide/tkz-obj-eu-compass.te
x
2022/09/23 4.25c tkz-obj-eu-compass.tex
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-euclide/tkz-obj-eu-circles.te
x
2022/09/23 4.25c tkz-obj-eu-circles.tex
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-euclide/tkz-obj-eu-circles-by
.tex
2022/09/23 4.25c tkz-obj-eu-circles.tex
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-euclide/tkz-obj-eu-draw-angle
s.tex
2022/09/23 4.25c tkz-tool-eu-angles.tex
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-euclide/tkz-obj-eu-draw-circl
es.tex
2022/09/23 4.25c tkz-obj-eu-draw-circles.tex
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-euclide/tkz-obj-eu-draw-lines
.tex
2022/09/23 4.25c tkz-obj-eu-draw-lines.tex
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-euclide/tkz-obj-eu-draw-polyg
ons.tex
2022/09/23 4.25c tkz-obj-eu-polygons.tex
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-euclide/tkz-obj-eu-lines.tex
2022/09/23 4.25c tkz-obj-eu-lines.tex
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-euclide/tkz-obj-eu-points-by.
tex
2022/09/23 4.25c tkz-tools-eu-points-by.tex
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-euclide/tkz-obj-eu-points-rnd
.tex
2022/09/23 4.25c tkz-obj-eu-points-rnd.tex
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-euclide/tkz-obj-eu-points-spc
.tex
2022/09/23 4.25c tkz-obj-eu-points.tex
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-euclide/tkz-obj-eu-points-wit
h.tex
2022/09/23 4.25c tkz-obj-eu-points-with.tex
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-euclide/tkz-obj-eu-polygons.t
ex
2022/09/23 4.25c tkz-obj-eu-polygons.tex
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-euclide/tkz-obj-eu-protractor
.tex
2022/09/23 4.25c tkz-obj-eu-protractor.tex
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-euclide/tkz-obj-eu-sectors.te
x
2022/09/23 4.25c tkz-obj-eu-sectors.tex
) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-euclide/tkz-obj-eu-show.tex
2022/09/23 4.25c tkz-obj-eu-show.tex
)

./trsas.tex:9: Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/R' and I am 
going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.9 \tkzDrawCircle[R](O,\rayon pt)
                                  ;
? 
Process aborted

?
```

I use XeTex, pdflatex, Lua and no success so far.

Since it's working on overleaf so I'm suspecting if this is OS X issue or (locally) only my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With  4.25 `\tkzDrawCircle[R](O,\rayon pt)` is no longer a valid command.
The `online` version of `tkz-euclide` is therefore old and that's why the command is accepted. Now you must first define the circle with `\tkzDefCircle[R](O,1)` (now the unit is only the cm) and then `\tkzGetPoint{X}` to recover a point of the circle (see the documentation or the readme). Finally we draw the circle with `\tkzDrawCircle(A,X)`. 1 and X are here only for example, you can use what you want.

Comment: thank you. I see, now it's much simpler for me (after the update).